# Spring Boot Data JPA: Oracle error:- ORA-01867: the interval is invalid

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

For the below query, I am getting an error, **ORA-01867: the interval is invalid**

```
  @Query(value="select * from Customer s where s.CUS_ID=:customerid and s.INSERT_TM < systimestamp - INTERVAL ':threshold' MINUTE", nativeQuery=true)
    @List<Customers> getCustomers(@Param("customerid") String customerid, @Param("threshold") Integer threshold )
```

Error is with this statement

```
INTERVAL ':threshold' MINUTE
```

But if I hardcode the threshold field, then I am getting success response,

```
INTERVAL '5' MINUTE
```

I don't want to hardcode. Can someone tell me how do I fix this?

Comment: This is one of the cases where SQL Injection can come to the rescue. Concatenate the value as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to do below trick like below to make it work:

```
@Query"select * from Customer s where s.CUS_ID=:customerid and s.INSERT_TM < systimestamp - :threshold*INTERVAL '1' MINUTE"
 @List<Customers> getCustomers(@Param("customerid") String customerid, @Param("threshold") String threshold )
```

Just to prove multiplication works with interval, you can check this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=20117f635aa880c891bf59b392c5eb43)